# Switching build configuration from cmake link to proper version of boost library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, conan

I am using Cmake to build my C++ project and I am using conan to maintain my boost libraries.
My conanfile.txt is very simple,

```
[requires]
boost/1.71.0@conan/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

When I install boost from conan, I can use following commands,

```
conan install ..
```

Or,

```
conan install .. -s build_type=Debug
```

Both command install bost libraries in two different folders in my C:/.conan foler.

In CMakeLists.txt I have following lines to find boost

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       ON) 
set(Boost_USE_DEBUG_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_RELEASE_LIBS      OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED     ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
```

However, When I configure cmake,

```
cmake .. -DBoost_DEBUG=ON
```

it doesn't find the debug version of boost library. It always shows that it it pointing to release version. So naturally, the following command works,

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

However, following command failed,

```
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

as it is still trying to link ot release version.

How can I reconfigure my cmake and conan setup so that I can easily switch between debug and release version? Any suggestion?

Cheers,
M

Comment: Side note: I'd really recommend you to use `boost/1.71.0` reference (https://conan.io/center/boost/1.73.0/). This is the reference that corresponds to community curated recipe in Conan Center Index (https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to consume the libraries with `find_package(Boost)` you need to generate the corresponding files. Use the `cmake_find_package` generator (you need different folders for Debug and Release) or the `cmake_find_package_multi` one (both Debug and Release can live in the same folder). Just add them to your `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
boost/1.71.0

[generators]
cmake_find_package_multi
```

Now, you can call CMake from the command line, but you need to tell where to find the generated `FindBoost.cmake` files (or the `BoostConfig.cmake` if you are using the *multi* generator):

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=<path/to/dir/with/findcmake> [...more arguments]
```

Take into account that, if you are not using the `cmake` generator and the call to `conan_basic_setup`, you need to be sure that the configuration used to build the Boost binaries you are getting from Conan matches the one you are using to build your project (otherwise you might get linker errors).

Comment: So I added cmake_conan as @Alan Britel suggested and it looks like when I run >cmake .. it could find two verson of boost Debug and Release. I am using following syntex: 
conan_cmake_run(REQUIRES boost/1.71.0@conan/stable
                BASIC_SETUP 
                BUILD missing
                CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Release;Debug")
However, when I try to build using cmake --build . --config Debug or Release, it shows lining error. How can I spcify the library path or version during build command?
thanks.

Comment: So this is cmake script:

add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${BINARY}_run PRIVATE${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS})
target_link_libraries(${BINARY}_run PUBLIC ${CONAN_LIBS_DEBUG})
When I want to make debug I use cmake --build . --config Debug and I had to put  ${CONAN_LIBS_DEBUG}. For release command I had to add  ${CONAN_LIBS_RELEASE}. I could link and executables work. Hoever, I want to do it in a way so that I don't need to edit the cmake and switch LIB configuration.

Comment: You can use the `debug` and `optimized` keyword in the `target_link_libraries`. You can write this single line: `target_link_libraries (${BINARY}_run debug ${CONAN_LIBS_DEBUG} optimized ${CONAN_LIBS_RELEASE})` and CMake will use different libraries depending on the build type.

Comment: Here is what I have in my CMakeList.txt.
add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${BINARY}_run PRIVATE${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS})
target_link_libraries(${BINARY}_run debug ${CONAN_LIBS_DEBUG} optimized ${CONAN_LIBS_RELEASE})
Problem is, > cmake --build . --config Debug works. But > cmake --build . --config Release has a linking problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already I'd recommend using https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan it makes life easier in some areas.

Unless you want to be able to build your project without conan there is no real need to use `find_package` with conan. See https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html. You can either use:

```
conan_basic_setup()

target_link_libraries(<target> ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Or:

```
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

target_link_libraries(<target> CONAN_PKG::boost)
```

If you want to use `find_package` you need to use the [cmake_find_package generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html)  and add the following to your `conanfile.txt`:

```
[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```